# Textfield becomes not visible or invisible after checking a specific option in my checkbox in PowerApps. What do I need to correct?

Tags: checkbox, textfield, powerapps, checkboxlist

It is not working ;(.
Let me write it down like this

The checkbox name is: Categories Checkbox
This checkbox has 4 options you can check: "clients", "employees", "consumers", "other"

I have a TextInput1 which I only want it to be visible if the option "Other" from the checkbox "Categories Checkbox" is checked.

This is why I am using this formula but it is not working :
If('Categories Checkbox'.Value = "other",true,false)

What do I need to correct? Can somebody please write me down the correct formula?

I tried to change the name of my checkbox,
I also tried to make the first letter a capital letter of "Other" instead of "other"
I also changed the Value in the formula to text
I also changed the textfield,which was text area to Single line of text in the Dataverse Table.
But still if I check or uncheck "other" then the textfield does not appear.

Comment: Are you adding the formula (If('Categories Checkbox'.Value = "other",true,false)) to the TextInput1.Visible property?

Comment: Yes, indeed, i did add the  (If('Categories Checkbox'.Value = "other",true,false)) to the TextInput1.Visible property. Do you know what I have to correct?

Comment: I tried this in a test App.  A checkbox value property is only ever true or false.
Are you sure you're using a checkbox?

Comment: I am 100% i am using a checkbox. the functionality also works as a checkbox.

Comment: A checkbox only has a Text property.  Do you mean you've added multiple checkboxes?

Comment: Yeah, there are 4 checkboxes ans i only want yhe textfield to be visible when you check the 4th checkbox.

Comment: I got confused as you said in your original question - there is a checkbox with 4 options.
So in your scenario, your formula should use 
If('Categories Checkbox'.Value = true,true,false))

Comment: I saw what I did was not wrong UIX wise but in the code it did not work.
Initialy I added the checkboxes in the form but that was not a good Idea.

I deleted the form and Have added the checkboxes manually, then added all the code for all checkboxes in the end on a submitbutton.